# Loading GAMS Java API in JRuby

Tags: java, ruby, linux, jruby, gams-math

I'm working on a Java/JRuby project which needs to be able to be able to interact with GAMS. I know we can use the Java API, but I would really like to be able to access it using JRuby if possible, since we're hoping to eventual add a DSL and some other complexity I'm not really excited about having to implement in pure Java.

Following the official Java API [documentation](http://www.gams.com/dd/docs/api/GAMS_java.pdf) for GAMS, I have downloaded and setup everything necessary to run GAMS from the command line, but I can't figure out how to include the GAMS directory in LD_LIBRARY_PATH and still run JRuby irb. When I run

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/wikk/Downloads/gams24.0_linux_x64_64_sfx`

Then try to run irb with JRuby, I get

`jruby: /home/wikk/Downloads/gams24.0_linux_x64_64_sfx/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by jruby)`

I think this is what the documentation is asking me to do to run a Java program that calls the API, is there maybe some way to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in irb, but before importing all the Java class files? I can do this successfully if I don't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but then GAMS tells me it can't find the main program when I try to create a new GAMSWorkspace object:

```
irb(main):002:0> ws = GAMSWorkspace.new
Java::ComGamsApi::GAMSException: could not find a GAMS system directory from 
your environment variable, please set up properly before running a program!
  from com.gams.api.GAMSWorkspace.verifySystemDirectory(GAMSWorkspace.java:335)
```

Am I doing this wrong? or does the API require some Java feature that isn't implemented in JRuby?

Comment: I've now gotten this working on windows w/ JRuby, it looks like I had my path set wrong in the above, and you need to set java.library.path as well for it to work properly. If I can get this working on linux I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally came back to this problem, got it working through some trial and error. I also needed to run jruby with the `-J-Djava.library.path=[GAMSDIR]/apifiles/Java/api` flag, and add `[GAMSDIR]/apifiles/Java/api/GAMSJavaAPI.jar` to the classpath.

Once this is all in place, you can run gams models from ruby scripts:

```
    import com.gams.api.GAMSWorkspace
    import com.gams.api.GAMSJob
    import com.gams.api.GAMSVariable
    import com.gams.api.GAMSVariableRecord
    import com.gams.api.GAMSWorkspace

    ws = GAMSWorkspace.new

    j1 = ws.addJobFromGamsLib('trnsport')

    j1.run

    j1.out_db.get_variable('x').each_entry do |rec|
      puts "x(#{rec.get_keys[0]}, #{rec.get_keys[1]}): level = #{rec.get_level},   marginal = #{rec.get_marginal}"
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing here because it is the only thread related to the GAMS Java API problem.

In Eclipse, you have to go to "Run Configurations" and add two things:
1. (As already said) add a "-Djava.library.path=[GAMSDIR]\apifiles\Java\api\" to VM arguments
2. Go to Environment and SET explicitly a PATH variable to [GAMSDIR]. For some reason seeting path through windows is not working